# Forms in Ruby on Rails and MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to make a simple form that saves the results to a database. Also how to make a spreadsheet from a database? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answer to your question.  A couple of good places to start for the forms aspect would be the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/).

As for the spreadsheet... well... that is a whole lot more. Once you have gone through the first two resources and done a few practice apps you should check out the [Spreadsheet Library](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/) at Rubyforge

Comment: up-voted for your patience and tolerance of fellow man.